# Send Receiver Information on Express checkout using Active Merchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I'm using `Activemerchant` to integrate express checkout in my eCommerce site.

I'm doing this on my controller side

```
def express_checkout
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

    paypal_options = {
        login: "MY SANDBOX LOGIN",
        password: "MY PASSWORD",
        signature: "MY Signature",
        appid: "APP-80W284485P519543T"
    }
    gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)

    response = gateway.setup_purchase(1000,
                                      ip: request.remote_ip,
                                      return_url: "http://esignature.lvh.me:3000/en/transactions/status",
                                      cancel_return_url: "http://esignature.lvh.me:3000/en/transactions/status",
                                      currency: "USD",
                                      allow_guest_checkout: true,
                                      items: [{name: "Order", description: "Order description", quantity: "1", amount: 1000}]
    )
    
    redirect_to gateway.redirect_url_for(response.token)

  end
```

It redirects me to paypal page and I'm able to perform the transaction successfully.But unfortunately I can't see any transaction on PayPal side neither on Seller side nor on Buyer side.

My assumption is seller account is same account that I used API credentials.
Is there any way to send receiver information?Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thank you

## EDIT 1

After transaction It gets redirect to `status` page and while view the transaction details

Here is my output.

```
    EXPRESS_GATEWAY.details_for(params[:token])
=> #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse:0x007f81122b6430
 @authorization=nil,
 @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil},
 @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil},
 @emv_authorization=nil,
 @error_code=nil,
 @fraud_review=false,
 @message="Success",
 @params=
  {"timestamp"=>"2015-10-13T06:58:27Z",
   "ack"=>"Success",
   "correlation_id"=>"591914b738b78",
   "version"=>"124",
   "build"=>"18308778",
   "token"=>"EC-0AB53385410155352",
   "payer"=>"vikas@esignature.com.np",
   "payer_id"=>"3GHXVQ2K8S5LQ",
   "payer_status"=>"verified",
   "salutation"=>nil,
   "first_name"=>"Vikas",
   "middle_name"=>nil,
   "last_name"=>"Lamichhane",
   "suffix"=>nil,
   "payer_country"=>"US",
   "payer_business"=>nil,
   "name"=>"Order",
   "street1"=>"1 Main St",
   "street2"=>nil,
   "city_name"=>"San Jose",
   "state_or_province"=>"CA",
   "country"=>"US",
   "country_name"=>"United States",
   "postal_code"=>"95131",
   "address_owner"=>"PayPal",
   "address_status"=>"Confirmed",
   "billing_agreement_accepted_status"=>"false",
   "order_total"=>"12.34",
   "order_total_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "item_total"=>"12.34",
   "item_total_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "shipping_total"=>"0.00",
   "shipping_total_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "handling_total"=>"0.00",
   "handling_total_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "tax_total"=>"0.00",
   "tax_total_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "phone"=>nil,
   "address_id"=>nil,
   "external_address_id"=>nil,
   "address_normalization_status"=>"None",
   "quantity"=>"1",
   "tax"=>"0.00",
   "tax_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "amount"=>"12.34",
   "amount_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "ebay_item_payment_details_item"=>nil,
   "description"=>"Order description",
   "insurance_total"=>"0.00",
   "insurance_total_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "shipping_discount"=>"0.00",
   "shipping_discount_currency_id"=>"USD",
   "insurance_option_offered"=>"false",
   "seller_details"=>nil,
   "payment_request_id"=>nil,
   "order_url"=>nil,
   "soft_descriptor"=>nil,
   "checkout_status"=>"PaymentActionNotInitiated",
   "payment_request_info"=>nil,
   "transaction_id"=>nil,
   "parent_transaction_id"=>nil,
   "receipt_id"=>nil,
   "transaction_type"=>"none",
   "payment_type"=>"none",
   "exchange_rate"=>nil,
   "payment_status"=>"None",
   "pending_reason"=>"none",
   "reason_code"=>"none",
   "Token"=>"EC-0AB53385410155352",
   "PayerInfo"=>
    {"Payer"=>"vikas@esignature.com.np",
     "PayerID"=>"3GHXVQ2K8S5LQ",
     "PayerStatus"=>"verified",
     "PayerName"=>{"Salutation"=>nil, "FirstName"=>"Vikas", "MiddleName"=>nil, "LastName"=>"Lamichhane", "Suffix"=>nil},
     "PayerCountry"=>"US",
     "PayerBusiness"=>nil,
     "Address"=>{"Name"=>"Vikas Lamichhane", "Street1"=>"1 Main St", "Street2"=>nil, "CityName"=>"San Jose", "StateOrProvince"=>"CA", "Country"=>"US", "CountryName"=>"United States", "PostalCode"=>"95131", "AddressOwner"=>"PayPal", "AddressStatus"=>"Confirmed"}},
   "BillingAgreementAcceptedStatus"=>"false",
   "PaymentDetails"=>
    {"OrderTotal"=>"12.34",
     "ItemTotal"=>"12.34",
     "ShippingTotal"=>"0.00",
     "HandlingTotal"=>"0.00",
     "TaxTotal"=>"0.00",
     "ShipToAddress"=>
      {"Name"=>"Vikas Lamichhane",
       "Street1"=>"1 Main St",
       "Street2"=>nil,
       "CityName"=>"San Jose",
       "StateOrProvince"=>"CA",
       "Country"=>"US",
       "CountryName"=>"United States",
       "Phone"=>nil,
       "PostalCode"=>"95131",
       "AddressID"=>nil,
       "AddressOwner"=>"PayPal",
       "ExternalAddressID"=>nil,
       "AddressStatus"=>"Confirmed",
       "AddressNormalizationStatus"=>"None"},
     "PaymentDetailsItem"=>{"Name"=>"Order", "Quantity"=>"1", "Tax"=>"0.00", "Amount"=>"12.34", "EbayItemPaymentDetailsItem"=>nil, "Description"=>"Order description"},
     "InsuranceTotal"=>"0.00",
     "ShippingDiscount"=>"0.00",
     "InsuranceOptionOffered"=>"false",
     "SellerDetails"=>nil,
     "PaymentRequestID"=>nil,
     "OrderURL"=>nil,
     "SoftDescriptor"=>nil},
   "CheckoutStatus"=>"PaymentActionNotInitiated",
   "PaymentRequestInfo"=>nil,
   "PaymentInfo"=>{"TransactionID"=>nil, "ParentTransactionID"=>nil, "ReceiptID"=>nil, "TransactionType"=>"none", "PaymentType"=>"none", "ExchangeRate"=>nil, "PaymentStatus"=>"None", "PendingReason"=>"none", "ReasonCode"=>"none", "SellerDetails"=>nil}},
 @success=true,
 @test=true>
```

Comment: I've got the same problem, although on PHP environment... could it be an issue on PayPals side?

Comment: I got the solution but due to busy hour I'm unable to answer the qns.My solution is after `setup_purchase`  we need to do `purchase`  as a final step In order to complete the transaction